# Visual studio code auto-complete

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I have just downloaded unity and saw that now it supports Visual studio code, I downloaded it and made it the default editor.

After trying to edit a script, it prompted me to download c# extension and I did, but there is no auto-complete for unity functions. How can I get that? I'm on Mac. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)

Answer (score 22):

Maybe too late, but for future comers ...

There is an extension now for visual studio code called [MonoBehaviour Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zrachod.mono-snippets) by [Rachod Petchpho](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/zrachod).

Press `Ctrl+shift+x` in the IDE to open extensions panel then search for `MonoBehaviour Snippets`, install and reload the IDE, now you will find all the autocomplete for the function names and objects just like MonoDevelop.

Comment: Awesome project in place of a similar that automatically injected massive commenting everywhere.  This is a great tool! thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same situation and I bang my head to the wall for days. There was no solution on the net as there are few people using Unity on linux with Visual Studio Code. I finally removed mono and went to their site and downloaded the Visual Studio build (even though we use Visual Studio Code). Then volaaa. Auto complete and suggestions related to Unity functions were there. Of course after installing the necessary extensions.

https://www.mono-project.com/download/vs/

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: it helps in my Mac too

Comment: Worked on Fedora 31

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with Unity + VS Code combo.

I have found an extension called [Unity CodeSnippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets)

I highly recommend to download it. This is much better than any of other snippets collection for VSCode.

Answer (score 5):

Intellisense (Autocompletion) is a pure workflow of .Net Environment. So, you need to have .Net 'Developer pack' (not Runtime) installed on your system as it installs all three necessary components below:

1. .Net framework
2. .Net Target pack
3. .net SDK

reference link: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks

It is directly installed to a system admin-accessible path, so no need setting it up. Now, you have to tell VS Code which .Net version to use (whichever you have installed).
Your Unity project will have these two files in the root directory:

1. Assembly-CSharp.cs
2. Assembly-CSharp-Editor.cs

In these both files search for line (probably 16):

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Edit version that you had just installed (I had 4.8). Then reopen VS Code. Now everything should work fine.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to go to Edit > Preferences > External Tools in Unity and set the external script editor to Visual Studio Code, then I clicked "regenerate project files" to get Assembly-CSharp.csproj to show up in my project folder.

Comment: Now, you have to tell VS Code which .Net version to use>> But HOW ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unity integration plugin:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/unity

Follow the instructions to get set up. It seems a lot of things to do but I think that's the best one.

If you still hit the issue even by using that plugin then follow [this issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/371) at their github page.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem like unity actually supports VSC or even has an official extension for it. For now I will just stick with Mono.

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-get-vscode-to-work-properly-with-unity.538224/

there are people that found a workaround.
unityoracle user said:
"This issue is that Unity Editor expects the file used to launch VSCode to have a specific name. "
and:
"Specifically, creating a symlink named "code" that opens VSCode fixed this issue"

Comment: What helped from there was Assets -> Open C# project. I also installed Mono (also a recommendation there)

Answer (score 0):

for me, it works by downloading .NET Framework 4.7.1 Developer Pack
here
[here is the link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net471)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Then in unity editor, set VS Code as the default Script editor:

Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools -> External Script Editor

Right below, set Embedded packages and Local packages to true

Answer (score 0):

i used these methods and it worked

1. Change in External Tools: Edit -> Preferences :choose " Visual Studio Code"
2. Open file : Assembly-CSharp-Editor in your project folder and Download the Framework Version that is the same as the version in this file EX: v4.7.1
3. Open VScode tool - Settings - >code lens and tick.

source from here:
https://www.gamesmobile.one/2022/01/visual-studio-code-auto-complete-with.html

Answer (score -3):

I installed an older version of `c# vscode extension`, `version 1.16.21`, and it is working.