# How to fix auto complete in VS code when working in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

so i like VS code and i am using it for web dev and all other languages and its fine so far. I just came back to develop with unity and using vs Code is a disaster for me. I got everything setup right just as I wanted but for some reason there is no auto complete...

i am trying to write `Input.Getinput` but it is referring me back to my function because it has input in its name...

I have tried researching this issue but it seems that it happens in visual studio too when the file is miscellaneous. I dunno what is the solution for visual studio code though.

Comment: If you have not gone through this docs,first visit this.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity If the problem persist then, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983371/visual-studio-code-auto-complete) can anwser your question Also try googling "autocomplete vscode unity"

Comment: Nothing from the above works i tried it all. it seems like there is no support for vscode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio

this one

Comment: Punit Jain he is talking about vs code. Your link above at stack overflow is for vs only. Zyzz, are you on Linux?

Comment: @AykutKaraca No i am on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues in the past. What worked for me:

1) Make sure Unity and VS are closed

2) Remove all the visual studio files from your unity project folder (*.csproj)

3) remove the Library/Temp folders

4) Start your project in Unity

5) Open a .cs or .js file from within unity by double clicking it.

Visual studio will take slightly longer to open since it's going to re-create all the VS project files, but hopefully you get no more invalid compiler errors, and autocompletion works again.

Hope this helps

(duplicate answer from here:
[Visual Studio doesn't correspond with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697516/visual-studio-doesnt-correspond-with-unity/56698013?noredirect=1#comment99960613_56698013)
)